# Reading a tarfile into BytesIO

Tags: python, byte, tar

I'm using [Docker-py](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#docker.api.container.ContainerApiMixin.put_archive) API to handle and manipulate `Docker` containers. In the `API`, the `put_archive()` function expects the `data` field to be in bytes.
So, using the `tarfile` library I have:

```
import tarfile
import io

container = client.create_container(image="myimage", command="/bin/bash")
source = "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
tarfile = create_tar_file(path=source, name="keys.tar")
# tarfile = "keys.tar"
# How can I read the tar file was a BytesIO() object?
data = io.BytesIO()
client.put_archive(container=container, path="/tmp", data=data)
```

The API says:

> **`put_archive`**(*`container`*, *`path`*, *`data`*)
>
> Insert a file or folder in an existing container using a tar archive as source.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> **container** (*str*) – The container where the file(s) will be extracted.
>              **path** (*str*) – Path inside the container where the file(s) will be extracted. Must exist.
>              **data** (*bytes*) – tar data to be extracted
>
> **Returns**: **`True`** if the call succeeds.
>
> **Return type:** (bool)
>
> **Raises**: **`docker.errors.APIError`** – If the server returns an error.

---

My question is:

How can I read the tar file as a `BytesIO()` so it can be passed to the `put_archive()` function?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could do this way (untested because I don't have`Docker-py` installed):

```
with open('keys.tar', 'rb') as fin:
    data = io.BytesIO(fin.read())
```